# Create XtraReports with parameters with: (stored procedures with parameters)

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, parameters, devexpress

I have a question related with Xtra Reports and stored Procedures with parameters.

I've been using XtraReports not for long, yet I have learned a lot.  The thing is that I haven't been able to complete one task the right way.

Let me explain:

In my DataSet I have one `SP_get_singleRecord` which has 2 parameters `(@ID, @TYPE) /*string,int*/` and the table has 6 columns.

So, I add the `dataset(dataset1)`, `dataMember(SP_get_singleRecord)` and `dataAdapter(SP_get_singleRecord_TableAdapter)` to the xtraReport.
I use the wizard to set the fields on place.

Now I go to the parameter section on xtrareports' fieldList and I add parameter `ID` as `string` and `TYPE` as `int`.

Then I go to the filter string and set the parameters like this:
`[ID] = ?ID And [TYPE] = ?TYPE`

Now, I go to the windowsForm -> print_simplebuttonEvent_OnClick

I pass the parameters silently like this:

```
private void btn_print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //convert parameters from controls
        int type = Convert.ToInt32(lookUpEdit_Type.EditValue);
        string id = lookUpEdit_id.EditValue.ToString();

        // Create a report instance
        Xtrareport report = new Xtrareport();

        // Obtain a parameter, and set its value.
        report.ID.Value = id;
        report.TYPE.Value = type;

        // Hide the Parameters UI from end-users.
        report.ID.Visible=false;
        report.TYPE.Visible = false;

        // Show the report's print preview.
        report.ShowPreview();
    }
```

Then I get an error message that says: `Error when trying to populate the datasource. The following exception was thrown: Procedure or function 'SP_getSingleRecord' expects parameter '@ID' which was not supplied.`

According to that, the parameters I've passed never reached the stored procedure.
I'm trying to get a single record before printing the report but I don't know what am I missing here...

*I've tried another way to do it but that involves changing the 'SP_getSingleRecord' for 'SP_getALLRecords' (with no parameters). That returns around 6500+ records and then filter them from the side of the report but that takes 9 seconds which is not acceptable...
It works, but it's not the right way...*

I hope I've made myself clear.
I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Alfred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

- set connection strings

  ```
  SP_get_singleRecord_TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString
  ```

  if you have any
- then add this to your Button click event (to the start of it...)

  ```
  SP_get_singleRecord_TableAdapter.Fill(dataset1.Yourdatatable, Convert.ToInt32(lookUpEdit_Type.EditValue), lookUpEdit_id.EditValue.ToString())
  ```
- On your XtraReport remove your data adapter:

  ```
  dataAdapter(SP_get_singleRecord_TableAdapter)
  ```
- also make sure that at the very bottom of yor `XtraReport` only the `DataSet` is shown (no data members, no table adapters..)

Comment: you do not need to pass the parameters silently and also `Report.DataSource = dataset1.SP_get_singleRecord` right after initializing the Report.

Answer (score 0):

well it turns up that i got it working.
I didn't know about some specific functions that devxpress and xtrareports have.

this was on the report side.
*both parameters should be public.
* as @Milen Pavlov said, report must not have datamembers, but i got it with only the data source and the data adapter.

```
private void XtraReport1_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
       spGetSingleRecord_tableadapter.Fill(
            (this.DataSource as DataSet1).spGetSingleRecord, Parameters["ID"].Value.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(Parameters["TYPE"].Value));
// the parameters are the ones on the report, not the stored procedure.

    }
```

and in the form side:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();

        report.RequestParameters = false;
        report.ID.Value = lookupedit1.editvalue;
        report.TYPE.Value = lookupedit2.editvalue;
        report.ID.Visible = false;
        report.TYPE.Visible = false;

        report.ShowPreview();
        report.PrintingSystem.ExecCommand(DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintingSystemCommand.Parameters, new object[] { true });

    }
```

it was very helpful!

Comment: Where do the XtraReport1 and Dataset1 types come from?